# Why Android ndk AImageReader_acquireNextImage does not work?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-camera2

I am trying to rotate camera captured image. However, AImageReader_acquireNextImage returns AMEDIA_IMGREADER_NO_BUFFER_AVAILABLE. I checked the return value of that function, and the return value indicates there is no available buffer space in queue. I think it means the queue for image reader is already full. Does any one know how to clear queue or solve this problem? The source code is bellow.
thank you in advance.

```
//open camera device
openCamera(0, &mainCameraDevice);

mainNativeWindow = ANativeWindow_fromSurface(env, surface);

AImageReader *yuvReader_;
media_status_t m_status = AImageReader_new(640, 380, AIMAGE_FORMAT_YUV_420_888,
                                         3, &yuvReader_);
if (m_status != AMEDIA_OK) {
    LOGE("Failed to create AImageReader");
}

m_status = AImageReader_getWindow(yuvReader_, &mainNativeWindow);
if (m_status != AMEDIA_OK) {
    LOGE("Could not get ANativeWindow");
}

ACaptureSessionOutput_create(mainNativeWindow, &mainSessionOutput);
ACaptureSessionOutputContainer_create(&mainCaptureSessionOutputContainer);

ACaptureSessionOutputContainer_add(mainCaptureSessionOutputContainer, mainSessionOutput);
ACameraOutputTarget_create(mainNativeWindow, &mainCameraOutputTarget);

ACameraDevice_createCaptureRequest(mainCameraDevice, TEMPLATE_PREVIEW, &mainCaptureRequest);

ACaptureRequest_addTarget(mainCaptureRequest, mainCameraOutputTarget);

ACameraDevice_createCaptureSession(mainCameraDevice, mainCaptureSessionOutputContainer, &captureSessionStateCallbacks, &mainCaptureSession);

ACameraCaptureSession_setRepeatingRequest(mainCaptureSession, NULL, 1, &mainCaptureRequest, NULL);

AImage *image;
m_status = AImageReader_acquireNextImage(yuvReader_, &image);
if (m_status == AMEDIA_IMGREADER_NO_BUFFER_AVAILABLE ) {
    LOGI("invalid parameter");
}
if (m_status != AMEDIA_OK ) {
    LOGI("invalid parameter");
}

AImage_delete(image);
```

Comment: it probably telling the truth: setRepeatingRequst() would need some time to acquire images from physical camera, and it is async; image will be available later and when it is available, application will be notified via callback interface  -- only inside the callback you could know you got image to process.  could you try it that way? could you log the time between setRepeatRequest() and the first call from your image's listener callback?

Comment: Thank you. So, you mean i should get images from camera in capture callback function. right?

Comment: yeah. mainly is about the timing too: only when inside the callback, you know exactly at that time the first image is available ( at least one image is available ).  Camera is all callback interfaces, all listeners are callbacks from camera to application: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/camera